# Solve recurrence relation in which there is a separate relation for even and odd values

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

[image]

Can someone help me how to solve these type of questions? What kind of approach should I follow?

Comment: Please provide a description of the problem in the question. I'm not going to be opening images to help solve something.

Comment: f(n+2)=2*f(n+1)-f(n)+2 if n is even
f(n+2)=3*f(n) if n is odd
 I need help to solve this recurrence relation
@ThomasJager

Comment: ...and what did YOU to solve the problem?

Comment: Well I don't know how to approach the problem ..actually never encountered a recurrence Relation of this type @ReinhardMänner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the question, since you will be asked to

- evaluate the recurrence lots of times
- for very large inputs,

you will likely need to either

- find a closed-form solution to the recurrence, or
- find a way to evaluate the nth term of the recurrence in sublinear time.

The question, now, is how to do this. Let's take a look at the recurrence, which was defined as

- f(1) = f(2) = 1,
- f(n+2) = 3f(n) if n is odd, and
- f(n+2) = 2f(n+1) - f(n) + 2 if n is even.

Let's start off by just exploring the recurrence to see if any patterns arise. Something that stands out here - the odd terms of this recurrence only depend on other odd terms in the recurrence. This means that we can imagine trying to split this recurrence into two smaller recurrences: one that purely deals with the odd terms, and one that purely deals with the even terms. Let's have D(n) be the sequence of the odd terms, and E(n) be the sequence of the even terms. Then we have

- D(1) = 1
- D(n+2) = 3D(n)

We only need to evaluate D on odd numbers, so we can play around with that to see if a pattern emerges:

- D(2·0 + 1) = 1 = 3<sup>0</sup>
- D(2·1 + 1) = 3 = 3<sup>1</sup>
- D(2·2 + 1) = 9 = 3<sup>2</sup>
- D(2·3 + 1) = 27 = 3<sup>3</sup>

The pattern here is that D(2n+1) = 3<sup>n</sup>. And hey, that's great news! That means that we have a direct way of computing D(2n+1).

With that in mind, notice that E(n) is defined as

- E(2) = 1 = D(1)
- E(n+2) = 2D(n+1) - E(n) + 2

Remember that we know the exact value of D(n+1), which is going to make our lives a lot easier. Let's see what happens if we iterate on this recurrence a bit. For example, notice that

> E(8)
>
> = 2D(7) - E(6) + 2
>
> = 2D(7) + 2 - (2D(5) - E(4) + 2)
>
> = 2D(7) - 2D(5) + E(4)
>
> = 2D(7) - 2D(5) + (2D(3) - E(2) + 2)
>
> = 2D(7) - 2D(5) + 2D(3) + 2 - D(1)
>
> = 2D(7) - 2D(5) + 2D(3) - D(1) + 2

Okay... that's really, really interesting. It seems like we're getting an alternating sum of the D recurrence, where we alternate between including and excluding 2. At this point, if I had to make a guess, I'd say that the way to solve this recurrence is going to be to think about subdividing the even case further into cases where the inputs are 2n for an even n and 2n for an odd n. In fact, notice that if the input is 2n for even n, then there won't be a +2 term at the end (all the +2's are balanced out by -2's), whereas if the input is odd, then there will be a +2 term at the end (all the +2's are balanced out by -2's).

Now, let's turn to a different aspect of the problem. You weren't asked to query for individual terms of the recurrence. You were asked to query for the sum of the recurrence, evaluated over a range of inputs. The fact that we're getting alternating sums and differences of the D terms here is really, really interesting. For example, what is f(10) + f(11) + f(12)? Well, we know that f(11) = D(11), which we can compute directly. And we also know that f(10) and f(12) are E(10) and E(12). And watch what happens if we evalute E(10) + E(12):

> E(10) + E(12)
>
> = (D(9) - D(7) + D(5) - D(3) + D(1) + 2) + (D(11) - D(9) + D(7) - D(5) + D(3) - D(1))
>
> = D(11) + (D(9) - D(9)) + (D(7) - D(7)) + (D(5) - D(5)) + (D(3) - D(3)) + (D(1) - D(1)) + 2
>
> = D(11) + 2.

Now *that's* interesting. Notice that all of the terms have cancelled out except for the D(11) term and the +2 term! More generally, this might lead us to guess that there's some rule about how to simplify E(n+2) + E(n). In fact, there is. Specifically:

> E(2n) + E(2n+2) = D(2n+1) + 2

This means that if we're summing up lots of consecutive values in a range, every pair of adjacent even terms will simplify instantly to something of the form D(2n+1) + 2.

There's still some more work to be done here. For example, you'll need to be able to sum up enormous numbers of D(n) terms, and you'll need to factor in the effects of all the +2 terms. I'll leave those to you to figure out.

One hint: all the values you're asked to return are modulo some number P. This means that the sequence of values 0, D(1), D(1) + D(3), D(1) + D(3) + D(5), D(1) + D(3) + D(5) + D(7), etc. eventually has to reach 0 again (mod P). You can both compute how many terms have to happen before this occurs and write down all the values encountered when doing this by just computing these values explicitly. That will enable you to sum up huge numbers of consecutive D terms in a row - you can mod the number of terms by the length of the cycle, then look up the residual sum in the table.

Hope this helps!